# What does the SQLAlchemy engine do?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What is the purpose of the SQLAlchemy engine?

How does the SQLAlchemy engine accomplish its goal?

I researched the concept on the official website but I couldn't fully understand it.

Comment: i think [aosa](http://aosabook.org/en/sqlalchemy.html) this is where it is explained.

Comment: One not too obvious benefit of SQLAlchemy is that it unifies database access packages.  Let's say you use mxodbc.  That has its own exceptions.  pyodbc?  Same thing.  So when you execute a query you need to import those exceptions to catch them.  SQLAlchemy supports a lot of underlying packages and databases (Oracle, Mysql, postgres, etc) and, even if you don't use the ORM, abstracts you away from the low level aspects, such as exact exception hierarchies.

Comment: sorry but until a few hours ago i didn't know some terms, now i know and it opened my eyes. That was not the question I wanted to ask. This is the [Doubt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707548/sqlalchemy-engine-and-pool-mechanisms).